# How to write Regexp for checking parts of url?

Tags: regex

Can someone help me to write RegExp for checking URL which look like this

```
"https://{some_unknown_part}

{this_part_I_know/e.g./domen1.com_or_domen2.org}"?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read [ask]. Provide [mcve].

Comment: As it is now, this would be a correct answer: `^https:\/\/{some_unknown_part}{this_part_I_know\/e\.g\.\/domen1\.com_or_domen2\.org}$`. You should add more examples, what you have tried, etc...

Comment: I must be sure that my string contain "https://" and "domain.com". Can I check it on single RegExp query? For Example I can control it with something like  `var url = "https://sometext.domain.com"; if (url.indexOf("https://") === 0 && url.indexOf("domain.com") !== -1) { console.log("this url is valid")  }`  OR another checkup `if (url.search(/https:\/\//i) === 0 && url.search(/domain.com/i) !== -1) ...` You see all time I need two conditions. But can I write a single condition using RexExp that would check my string?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. As of your comment, I understand it like that: The beginning of the string needs to be `https://` followed by some text and then `domain.com`? If so, you can use [`https:\/\/(?:.*?\.)?domain\.com.*`](https://regex101.com/r/nSEtaa/1)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. As of your comment, I understand it like that *(seems to be the case, so here the same as in the comments above also as an answer)*:

The beginning of the string needs to be `https://` followed by some text and then `domain.com`? If so, you can use

```
https:\/\/(?:.*?\.)?domain\.com.*
```

Here is a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/nSEtaa/1).